# Why can't gcc find libevent when building tmux from source?

Tags: compiling, make, configure, autoconf

I want to install tmux on a machine where I don't have root access. I already compiled libevent and installed it in `$HOME/.bin-libevent` and now I want to compile tmux, but configure always ends with `configure: error: "libevent not found"`, even though I tried to point to the libevent directory in the `Makefile.am` by modifying `LDFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS`, but nothing seems to work.

How can I tell the system to look in my home dir for the libevent?

Comment: An alternative is to investigate [dtach](https://github.com/crigler/dtach). Handy when you want detachable sessions, but don't have root and don't have time to statically compile tmux.

Comment: If you are on RHEL 6.x, there is a pre-compiled tmux in the repos.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try:

```
DIR="$HOME/.bin-libevent"
./configure CFLAGS="-I$DIR/include" LDFLAGS="-L$DIR/lib"
```

(I'm sure there must be a better way to configure library paths with autoconf. Usually there is a `--with-libevent=dir` option. But here, it seems there is no such option.)

Comment: This is the approach that made `make` finally work. I tried setting other environment variables and setting `prefix` and `exec-prefix`, but once I included these flags stuff actually got built.

Comment: How would I go about specifying multiple directories for the flags? I tried ```./configure CFLAGS="-I$DIR/include:/usr/otherdir" LDFLAGS="-L$DIR/lib:/usr/otherdir"``` but no success

Comment: @lucaswxp `CFLAGS="-Idir1 -Idir2 -Idir3" LDFLAGS="-Ldira -Ldirb -Ldirb"`

Comment: I used this answer and the `libevent not found` error went away, but now I get the same with `ncurses`: `curses not found`.

My `libevent` as well as `ncurses` installations are both in `$HOME/.local/`

Comment: For `libevent`, use `LIBEVENT_CFLAGS` and `LIBEVENT_LIBS` instead of `CFLASG` and `LDFLAGS`. For `ncurse`, use `LIBTINFO_CFLAGS` and `LIBTINFO_LIBS` @Aalok

Comment: This worked for me, but how does this work versus putting $HOME in the flag directly?

Answer (score 10):

I was having a similar problem and discovered that after running `sudo yum install libevent-devel` I was able to successfully make and install tmux.

EDIT: If you are installing this on a Red Hat machine, you will also need to visit the channels selection for your server on the Red Hat Network and add the RHEL Server Optional channel.  This will give you access to the -devel packages for libevent (the base and supplementary channels do not provide it).

Comment: This would be the normal way to fix it, but in this case it was "a machine where I don't have root access"

Comment: This helped me. I wasn't root and I hadn't installed the devel lib.

Comment: where do you get the devel lib as a tar file?

Comment: for my fedora machine, I also required to sudo yum install ncurses-devel besides sudo yum install libevent-devel

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue on RHEL 5.4 and actually found libevent is installed but there is no libevent.so symlink, only the real version of the library:

```
/usr/lib64/libevent-1.1a.so.1
/usr/lib64/libevent-1.1a.so.1.0.2
```

So, `ln -s /usr/lib64/libevent-1.1a.so.1 /usr/lib64/libevent.so` works pretty well for me without the need to install or alter anything. No idea why RedHat's libevent rpm didn't create the symlink. Maybe a bug to report?

But now, it's complaining for this: `error: event.h: No such file or directory`.

Comment: I got the same exact error: `error: event.h: No such file or directory`.

Comment: I'm on RHEL 6, and I just downloaded and compiled libevent, installing it to a user folder. Then I used @Stéphane Gimenez's trick above to get it compiling. To get it running, I aliases with the LD_PRELOAD trick given by @rozcietrzewiacz: `tmux='LD_PRELOAD=/opt-local/lib/libevent-2.0.so.5 /opt-local/bin/tmux'`. Works like a charm!

Comment: If you find yourself messing around with symlinks or manually copying things around in system directories, then there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Before the configuration and compilation of tmux (or any program) you need to tell it where it can find the libraries it needs. If you have installed some library in a non-standard location, you can use the environmental variable `LD_LIBRARY_PRELOAD` to tell, where some libraries are located.

I your case:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PRELOAD=$HOME/.bin-libevent/lib
```

And then go on with the configuration/compilation.

Later on, the binary will also need to know where your additional libraries can be found, so you'll need to place the `export` statement in your `.bashrc` (if bash is your login shell).

Comment: Thanks, but sadly this doesn't work, same error message. The version number is libevent-2.0.12 which should work

Comment: Then it seems there is a problem with your libevent compilation. What does `find .bin-libevent -name 'libevent.so*'` show?

Comment: `$ find .bin-libevent -name 'libevent.so*'` finds `.bin-libevent/lib/libevent.so`

Comment: :) Then you should point at the directory `$HOME/.bin-libevent/lib` (updated the answer)

Comment: Yes, I am afraid I already tried that as well, still no change. I am quite puzzled and frustrated.

Comment: The OP didn't mention which *nix he's using. On OSX,  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is equivalent to LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Linux.

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PRELOAD` is used when executing a binary. It is pretty useless for telling a linker where to find a library.

Answer (score 1):

There's a gist at https://gist.github.com/ryin/3106801:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script for installing tmux on systems where you don't have root access.
# tmux will be installed in $HOME/local/bin.
# It's assumed that wget and a C/C++ compiler are installed.

# exit on error
set -e

TMUX_VERSION=1.8

# create our directories
mkdir -p $HOME/local $HOME/tmux_tmp
cd $HOME/tmux_tmp

# download source files for tmux, libevent, and ncurses
wget -O tmux-${TMUX_VERSION}.tar.gz http://sourceforge.net/projects/tmux/files/tmux/tmux-${TMUX_VERSION}/tmux-${TMUX_VERSION}.tar.gz/download
wget https://github.com/downloads/libevent/libevent/libevent-2.0.19-stable.tar.gz
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-5.9.tar.gz

# extract files, configure, and compile

############
# libevent #
############
tar xvzf libevent-2.0.19-stable.tar.gz
cd libevent-2.0.19-stable
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local --disable-shared
make
make install
cd ..

############
# ncurses  #
############
tar xvzf ncurses-5.9.tar.gz
cd ncurses-5.9
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local
make
make install
cd ..

############
# tmux     #
############
tar xvzf tmux-${TMUX_VERSION}.tar.gz
cd tmux-${TMUX_VERSION}
./configure CFLAGS="-I$HOME/local/include -I$HOME/local/include/ncurses" LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/local/lib -L$HOME/local/include/ncurses -L$HOME/local/include"
CPPFLAGS="-I$HOME/local/include -I$HOME/local/include/ncurses" LDFLAGS="-static -L$HOME/local/include -L$HOME/local/include/ncurses -L$HOME/local/lib" make
cp tmux $HOME/local/bin
cd ..

# cleanup
rm -rf $HOME/tmux_tmp

echo "$HOME/local/bin/tmux is now available. You can optionally add $HOME/local/bin to your PATH."
```

Comment: I also had curses installed to a custom location (I'm not an admin on the target system), and didn't realize it installs itself to the `ncurses` subdirectory of whatever include/ library path you specify. Odd design choice. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is good, but as of at least tmux 2.8 there is support for specifying libevent location using environment variables.

First install libevent in desired location.  I used cmake because I had a problem with autoconf

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/usr ..
make install
```

Then build and install tmux:

```
export LIBEVENT_CFLAGS=-I${HOME}/usr/include 
export LIBEVENT_LIBS="-L${HOME}/usr/lib -levent" 
./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr
make install
```

The environment variable `LIBEVENT_CFLAGS` overrides `pkg-config` include settings for libevent, and `LIBEVENT_LIBS` overrides the linker flag settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and it seems the most upvoted answer didn't work for me. I am using Fedora 22 Workstation. Here is what I did to fix this:
1. Install `libevent-devel` package. 2. Install `ncurses-devel` package

```
$ dnf install libevent-devel`
$ dnf install ncurses-devel
```

First one will solve no `event.h` problem and second will solve cannot find curses problem. BTW, the softlink method above also works for me during `./configure`.

Comment: Not sure why it got downvoted. It fixed the issue for me on a CentOS system.

Answer (score 0):

This installed latest version of tmux and libevent,
worked for me on AWS Linux 2:

```
# Install tmux 3.3

# install deps
sudo yum install -y gcc kernel-devel make ncurses-devel

# DOWNLOAD SOURCES FOR LIBEVENT AND MAKE AND INSTALL
curl -LOk https://github.com/libevent/libevent/releases/download/release-2.1.11-stable/libevent-2.1.11-stable.tar.gz
tar -xf libevent-2.1.11-stable.tar.gz
cd libevent-2.1.11-stable
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install

# DOWNLOAD SOURCES FOR TMUX AND MAKE AND INSTALL

curl -LOk https://github.com/tmux/tmux/releases/download/3.3a/tmux-3.3a.tar.gz
tar -xf tmux-3.3a.tar.gz
cd tmux-3.3a
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib" ./configure --prefix=/usr/local 
make
sudo make install

# pkill tmux
# close your terminal window (flushes cached tmux executable)
# open new shell and check tmux version
tmux -V
```

Similar to this gist: https://gist.github.com/muralisc/dbb998a8555acc577ce2cf7aae8cd9fa

Answer (score -3):

On CentOS 6, compile and install libevent in `/opt/libevent` directory with the command:

```
# ./configure --prefix=/opt/libevent
# make
# make install
```

Then, install my aplication (in this case was PgBouncer)

```
# ./configure --prefix=/opt/ *--with-libevent=/opt/libevent/*
```

You can change the directories wherever you want.