# How do I build Tmux from source without root access with a custom-built libevent 2.1?

Tags: tmux

I want to use Tmux on a scientific computing cluster node, but it's not available in any of the [Environment Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) that I can see. So I went about to build it from source, without root access. `.configure` needed libevent, so I successfully downloaded and built libevent 2.1 in my home directory. However, I don't know how to specify libevent in Tmux's configure script. How can I do this?

NOTE: This question is very similar to [Why can't gcc find libevent when building tmux from source?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17907/why-cant-gcc-find-libevent-when-building-tmux-from-source), but I'm using libevent 2.1.

Comment: Do you have `libevent.pc` or something like that?

Comment: Yeah, I see it, but I'm not familiar with what it does or how it can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [Why can't gcc find libevent when building tmux from source?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17907/why-cant-gcc-find-libevent-when-building-tmux-from-source), there is no `with-libevent=dir` option. So do the following when configuring Tmux:

```
DIR="$HOME/path/to/libevent"
./configure CFLAGS="-I$DIR/include" LDFLAGS="-L$DIR/.libs"
```

Note that it's **.libs**, not lib. I assume this is a change in libevent 2.1.

This will get it to pass configure checks and compile. However, you're not out of the woods yet. If you only do this, then when you attempt to run `tmux`, you'll get this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libevent-2.1.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

[This blog post](http://isunix.github.io/blog/2016/07/12/tmux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libevent-2-dot-0-so-dot-5/.) has the solution - append the `.libs` path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, like so:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/path/to/libevent/.libs
```

Now, to get this to "stick" the next time you login, paste the line above into your `~/.bashrc` file. If you merely run the command in your terminal, it will only last for that session.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pkg-config`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config)
to do this easily.

First, build `libevent`.  In this example we will be installing
`libevent` to `/tmp/libevent` - you don't have to create this
directory manually, it will be created automatically during the build
process.  You do not need to be root to run `make install`:

```
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure  --prefix=/tmp/libevent
$ make
$ make install
```

You should now have `/tmp/libevent/lib/pkgconfig/libevent.pc`:

```
$ cat /tmp/libevent/lib/pkgconfig/libevent.pc
#libevent pkg-config source file

prefix=/tmp/libevent
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: libevent
Description: libevent is an asynchronous notification event loop library
Version: 2.2.0-alpha-dev
Requires:
Conflicts:
Libs: -L${libdir} -levent
Libs.private:
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

Notice that `prefix` is set to the directory we passed as an argument
to `./configure`.

Before building tmux   add `/tmp/libevent/lib/pkgconfig` to
`PKG_CONFIG_PATH`:

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/tmp/libevent/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs libevent
-I/tmp/libevent/include -L/tmp/libevent/lib -levent
```

And then build `tmux` normally:

```
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
```

Notice than in order to actually start `tmux` with your custom
`libevent` you have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` correctly:

```
$ ldd ./tmux
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffce3d92000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f2f1d77e000)
        libncurses.so.5 => /lib64/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007f2f1d527000)
        libevent-2.2.so.1 => not found
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f2f1d30b000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2f1cf42000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2f1cd3d000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055cdf0697000)
$ ./tmux
./tmux: error while loading shared libraries: libevent-2.2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/libevent/lib ./tmux -V
tmux master
```

**EDIT**:

In order to get away with setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` you can set `rpath` when building `tmux`:

```
$ ./configure LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath=/tmp/libevent/lib"
$ make
$ ldd ./tmux
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcc6de1000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fbe121a4000)
        libncurses.so.5 => /lib64/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007fbe11f4c000)
        libevent-2.2.so.1 => /tmp/libevent/lib/libevent-2.2.so.1 (0x00007fbe11cf7000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fbe11adc000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbe11712000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbe1150e000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbe112f1000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055f057ef4000)
 $ ./tmux -V
 tmux master
```

Comment: @dsstorefile1: see update

Answer (score 0):

Encountered similar problem when running tmux even after installing libevent-2.1.so.7. Creating symlink of the installed file to /lib64/ directory worked for me.

```
$sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libevent-2.1.so.7.0.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent-2.1.so.7

$ldd tmux
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff6f9fe000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f675b5eb000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f675b3c1000)
    libevent-2.1.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent-2.1.so.7 (0x00007f675b16b000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f675af50000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f675ab5f000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f675a940000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f675ba9f000)
```